# Hypergeometric distribution: less than ($P(X<k)$)

Tags: probability, distributions, hypergeometric-distribution

The [hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution) is given by
$$ P(X=k) = \frac{\binom Kk \binom {N-K}{n-k}}{\binom Nn} $$

Is there a nice expression for the less-than probability, $P(X< k)$?

Or am I just going to have to numerically evaluate the sum $\sum_{j<k}P(X=j)$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the hypergeometric is discrete with support over a set of non-negative integers, $P(X \lt k) = F(k - 1)$, where $F$ is the CDF of the hypergeometric distribution.

The formula for the CDF is given in the same [article you link to](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution). I'm not sure I'd call it nice, but it's widely implemented if you're looking for a ready solution.